Confusion about time reversion and the Feynman-Stuckelberg interpretation
The Dirac equation $(i\hbar\gamma^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}-mc)\psi(\mathbf{x},t) = 0$ admits solutions with positive and negative energies.
In the Feynmann-Stuckelberg interpretation we view negative energy particle soultions as positive energy anti-particle solutions moving backwards in time.
This means negative energy solutions in a reference system A, viewed from a reference system B which moves backwards in time relative to A appear to have a positive energy viewed from B.
The time reversal operator $T = i\gamma^1\gamma^3K$ ($K$ := complex conjugation) takes

$\psi_A(\mathbf{x},t) \mapsto \psi_B(\mathbf{x},t) =  T\psi_A(\mathbf{x}, -t)$,

where $\psi_B(\mathbf{x},t)$ is the Dirac-Spinor observed in $B$ a reference system which moves backwards in time relative to the first one.
Let $\psi_A(\mathbf{x},t)$ be a solution with energy and momentum $(E, \mathbf{p})$.
Then $\psi_B(\mathbf{x},t)$ will be a solution with $(E, \mathbf{-p})$ i.e. unchanged energy and opposite momentum.
How does that fit with the Feynmann-Stueckelberg interpretation

$\psi_B$ will have $(-E, \mathbf{p})$ -- opposite-sign energy and same momentum. The opposite-sign energy is kind of the point; reinterpreting negative energy solutions moving forward in time, as positive energy solutions moving back in time.

Here is an actual lecture given by Feynman where this topic is discussed in some detail:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MDZaM-Bi-kI
